# I can't get my app to respond when on moblie device, works fine on PC, even in mobile Test mode on PC

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a Web App using Angular, Bootstrap, and templated off of Ace Admin (Responsiveness template).  On the PC, in Chrome and FireFox everything works fine.  When we shrink the window or use the Responsive Design Review the sidebar navigation changes to a menu button and works appropriately.  However when we bring the site up on a table or phone (Chrome or Firefox browswers), the menu button is visible, but doesn't respond.  Any ideas?  Here is my opening HTML page, the only thing I have left off is the javascript for my app.  The rest is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<title>DISCUS Admin</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>

<!-- bootstrap & fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- page specific plugin styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ui.jqgrid.css">

<!-- text fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ace-fonts.css">

<!-- ace styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ace.min.css" id="main-ace-style">

<!-- ngModal styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ng-modal/ng-modal.css">

<!-- TEST DRIVE STYLES (Determine to keep or throw away) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ng-grid/ng-grid.css">

<!-- DSC styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ng-style.css">

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ace-part2.min.css">
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ace-skins.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ace-rtl.min.css">

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ace-ie.min.css">
<![endif]-->

<!-- inline styles related to this page -->

<!-- ace settings handler -->
<script src="resources/ace/assets/js/ace-extra.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML5shiv and Respond.js for IE8 to support HTML5 elements and media queries -->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="resources/ace/assets/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/ace/assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<!--<body class="no-skin">-->
<body class="skin-1" data-ng-controller="MainController">

<ng-include src="'views/navbar.html'"></ng-include>


<div class="main-container" id="main-container">

<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar                  responsive" data-ng-show="user">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            ace.settings.check('sidebar', 'fixed')
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    </script>

    <div class="sidebar-shortcuts" id="sidebar-shortcuts">
        <div class="sidebar-shortcuts-large" id="sidebar-shortcuts-large">
            <button class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-signal"></i>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-info">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </button>

            <!-- #section:basics/sidebar.layout.shortcuts -->
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users"></i>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-cogs"></i>
            </button>

            <!-- /section:basics/sidebar.layout.shortcuts -->
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar-shortcuts-mini" id="sidebar-shortcuts-mini">
            <span class="btn btn-success"></span>

            <span class="btn btn-info"></span>

            <span class="btn btn-warning"></span>

            <span class="btn btn-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar-shortcuts -->

    <div ng-include src="'views/sidebar.html'"></div>
    <!-- #section:basics/sidebar.layout.minimize -->
    <div class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left" data-icon1="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left"
           data-icon2="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </div>

    <!-- /section:basics/sidebar.layout.minimize -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
            ace.settings.check('sidebar', 'collapsed')
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    </script>
</div>


<div class="main-content">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
                <div ng-view></div>
                <!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.page-content -->
</div>
</div>


<!-- basic scripts -->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='resources/ace/assets/js/jquery.min.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
</script>

<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='resources/ace/assets/js/jquery1x.min.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) document.write("<script src='resources/ace/assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
</script>
```

```
<!-- page specific plugin scripts -->

<!-- ace scripts -->
<script src="resources/ace/assets/js/ace.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/ace/assets/js/ace-elements.min.js"></script>


<!-- inline scripts related to this page -->

<!-- the following scripts are used in demo only for onpage help and you don't need them -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/assets/css/ace.onpage-help.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/ace/docs/assets/js/themes/sunburst.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript"> ace.vars['base'] = '..'; </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/assets/js/ace/elements.onpage-help.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/assets/js/ace/ace.onpage-help.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/docs/assets/js/rainbow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/docs/assets/js/language/generic.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/docs/assets/js/language/html.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/docs/assets/js/language/css.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/docs/assets/js/language/javascript.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ace/assets/js/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/xeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-local-storage.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/Smart-Table.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ng-modal/ng-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/angular-highlightjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/pdfjs-mod/pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/directives/angular-pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/directives/partials-css.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ui-layout/ui-layout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
<!-- The following are for exporting from ui-grid -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ui-grid/csv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ui-grid/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ui-grid/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

<!-- TEST DRIVE SCRIPTS (Determine to keep or throw away) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/ng-grid/ng-grid-2.0.11.debug.js"></script>

<!-- DISCUS-NG Angular JavaScript -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In searching Stack Overflow I found a somewhat related issue and did some trial and error.  My issue turned out to be a conflict between Angular and the Ace Admin template.  I ended up moving two Ace JavaScript calls to after the Angular calls (ace.min.js and ace-elements.min.js) and suddenly the toggled menu button works on PC and mobile device in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

> Most mobile browsers wait about 300ms after a tap-and-release before sending the click event.

Using the ngTouch module, which provides an ngClick replacement might solve this for you:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick

Comment: Thanks dsbaars.  We did try ngTouch and had the same result.  I posted my answer -- of course it comes shortly after I posted the question.  The problem was the order in which we were loading the angular and ace scripts.  Moved two ace scripts after angular and things worked.